# How Nasdaq trade matching is done?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, nasdaq, nyse

I don't understand how trade matching in Nasdaq is done.

I understand that there are 2 queues: one for buy orders, and one for sell orders. Each queue is sorted based on price, and then based on time. So that all the sell orders of 50$ per share will be before all the sell orders of 55$ per share. Within the 50$ offers, the earliest comes first.

Same for the buyers queue - the highest bids will be in the top of the queue.

When there's a match of the price between a bid and an ask, there'll be a trade executed.

But what I don't understand is - what happens when the top-most bid offers a higher price than the top-most offer. Say that the best bid offers to buy 100 shares at 50$ each, and the best sell offers to sell 100 shares at 45$ each.

How will the matching engine will work then? Is there a difference between the Nasdaq and the NYSE in that matter?

Thanks.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/153468/32127

Comment: Does this answer your question? [At what price does a stock get traded if the buy order price is higher than the sell order price?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/153468/at-what-price-does-a-stock-get-traded-if-the-buy-order-price-is-higher-than-the)